# Bootstrap columns with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I'm using ng-repeat and ng-show to display one element of an array at a time in a central div (col-xs-10).
There are two buttons (col-xs-1 each) added on the left and right of the central div. However, the right button is shifted down and only showed in the correct place after with the last element of the array.

Cannot figure out what I do wrong. Any ideas how to solve this?

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="!showTestimonials">
                    {{message}}
                </div>
                <!--BUTTON LEFT-->
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <span ng-click="leftClick()"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></span>
                </div>
                <!--START TESTIMONIAL-->
                <div class="col-xs-10" ng-repeat="testimonial in testimonials" ng-if="showTestimonials">
                    <div class="item text-center" ng-show="testimonial.id === active">
                        <div class="testimonial-text">
                            <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
                            <p>{{testimonial.description}}</p>
                            <img src="{{testimonial.img}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                            <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
                            <h4>{{testimonial.author}}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--- END COL --> 
                <!--BUTTON RIGHT-->
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <span ng-click="rightClick()"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div><!--- END ROW -->
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.active = 0;
$scope.rightClick = function () {
    if ($scope.active < ($scope.testimonials.length - 1)) {
        $scope.active +=1;
    } else {
        $scope.active = 0;
    }

    return  $scope.active;
};
$scope.leftClick = function () {
    if ($scope.active > 0 ) {
        $scope.active -=1;
    } else {
        $scope.active = 4;
    }

    return  $scope.active;
};
```

Screenshots:

[with last element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF3bp.jpg)

[with all other elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g4zt.jpg)

Comment: Toss this into a jsfiddle or plunker; it's much easier to help that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need ng-repeat here. All you need

```
1- create an active-testimonial object and initialize with    testimonials[0] and active-index=0 
2- on previous click get previous    element from the array and assign to active-testimonial 
3- on next    button click get the next testimonial and assign to active    testimonial.
```

Note: please take care of 0th index and last index of array of testimonials

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clean up some other things first, then the problem might go away or become more obvious.

Specifically, what you're switching on and off doesn't seem consistent: the `col-xs-1`'s don't have an `ng-show` rule, but I imagine the point is to only show them if `showTestimonials` is true. Also the `col-xs-12` might as well be in its own row. Then you can just toggle whole rows and there will be fewer surprises.

```
<div class="row" ng-show="!showTestimonials">
  <div class="col-xs-12">...</div>
</div>
<div class="row" ng-show="showTestimonials">
  <div class="col-xs-1">...</div>
  <div class="col-xs-10" ng-repeat="..." ng-show="testimonial.id == active">...</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">...</div>
</div>
```

Finally, make sure none of your CSS is adding margin or padding to `.row` or `.col*` elements, which could increase their width and make them wrap like in your screenshot.

Comment: I added row for the col-xs-12 and kept the other elements in another row as you suggested. This did not fix the issue unfortunately. Also, no margin or padding is addded to any of the elements. I belive it has something to do with ng-repeat as when inspecting the page, hidden div's shown as a line uder the col-xs-10 element (and also above it) and only then the botton on the right so it's shifted down.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle or plunker!